# In Swift 3 is it actually possible to test for a return type of Void (aka () )

Tags: swift3, ternary-operator

May seem like a strange question but bear with me.  I have written a function:

```
func togglePlay() {
   if _musicPlayer.isPlaying {
      _musicPlayer.pause()
   } else {
      _musicPlayer.play()
   }
}
```

That works but I thought, what about using the ternary operator instead of that if statement:

```
_musicPlayer.isPlaying ? _musicPlayer.pause() : _musicPlayer.play()
```

That gives a compiler error about mismatching types - pause() returns Void, play() returns Bool.  So I need to convert the return type of pause() to Bool in some way (test for Void).  I suppose alternatives might be:

1. Convert return type of play() to Void.
2. Use multiple statements within the ternary operator to add a Bool statement after pause()

Clearly, if this isn't possible then I have a working solution but it feels like there may be a part of Swift syntax that I don't know.

Comment: As a follow up, I can achieve what I want with:

`_musicPlayer.isPlaying ? _musicPlayer.pause() : (_ = _musicPlayer.play())`

effectively, swallowing the Bool return value.
Technically, this doesn't answer my question though.

Answer (score 0):

It is called the ternary *operator* for a reason, its purpose is to return a value. This is part of the world of *expressions*, program constructs which compute values.

The `if` statement selects between the execution of two *statements*, it does not return a value but an action.

The are some languages, termed *expression-oriented*, where traditionally statement constructs are expressions that return values. Swift is not one of them.

You have not missed anything in Swift, but as you have discovered you can abuse the language to treat the ternary operator like a conditional statement - but for the sake of clarity it is best not to.

Comment: I agree that it's a bit of an abuse - can't be a complete abuse as it compiles and works but certainly against the spirit of ternaries :)

I'm in the process of learning Swift, so trying out new syntactical elements as I discover them.  Given the nature of Swift, I'm surprised that a test like () == () isn't valid, so that was my real question - is it possible to test for a return value of Void aka ().

Comment: @ad-johnson An `==` overload for `Void` is coming to a future version of the language – https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/8354. Although I'm not sure I see how you could apply it in this case, as the only value `Void` can have is `Void`.

Comment: @Hamish - The OP could use it easily. They have a Bool/Void conflict in the ternary, the coming `==` overload you mention applied to the Void returns a Bool and so the conflict can be resolved. So the overall construct would be applying an additional operator, `==`, to enable the (ab)use of the ternary...

Comment: @ad-johnson - such a test, which Hamish states is coming, would allow what you wish - but at the cost of an extra operation, so you still wouldn't get brevity you seek. Keep exploring, an inquiring mind is a good thing!

Comment: @CRD Doh! That totally flew over my head. Although the entire expression would then evaluate to a `Bool` and generate a warning for not using it, so OP would then need to say `_ =` to swallow it. You could also abuse tuples to do it; `_ = _musicPlayer.isPlaying ? (_musicPlayer.pause(), true).1 : _musicPlayer.play()`. But as you say, this is a complete misuse of the ternary operator, and should be avoided.

Comment: @CRD you're right of course, it would be an extra test.  With the implementation I've shown in my follow up, it doesn't complain about not using the response.  I'll use my original code as that's clearly the right check to implement but it was a diverting thought exercise!